# Science fiction movie with a hallway lined with brains and a conveyor with saws

Tags: story-identification, movie

I've been looking for a old Scifi movie. The last time I saw it I was a kid it came on basic TV during, I think late 90s or early 2000s.

**Scenes I remember:**

- In outer space you have a ship with hallways lined with brains that can speak.
- There's screens where you have people on conveyors they start getting closer to the saws on the wall were they get what looks like gutted and then bagged.
- At the end, I'm not sure if it was a ship or something but it was a giant brain and it was showing screens where this guy's head was in it and still alive talking to the brain
- There was this other guy who was crawling, carrying a creature. Once he got to a certain point he let it go so it started to eat and destroy the brain. The guy then gets out before it blows up and it showed a image of the creature that destroyed the brain.

Comment: I’ve edited your question to try to make English out of it, but the third paragraph made so little sense that I’m not sure I’ve interpreted it correctly. Please check to see if I’ve introduced any errors with my edit (once it’s approved).

Comment: Oh, it seems Richard had the same idea and edited at the same time.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I've rolled it back to my earlier version.

Answer (score 24):

This is a pretty fair description of the made-for-TV movie-length pilot of Lexx, known as [**Lexx: I Worship his Shadow**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0631310/)

The scene with the brains is [here](https://youtu.be/SvqnjEQljYs?t=1266) and the scene with the choppers is [here](https://youtu.be/SvqnjEQljYs?t=15289) (Warning - **NSFW: Gory!!**)

Comment: Such a fantastic show. Highly recommended for anyone who has not seen it.

Answer (score 18):

This is [Lexx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexx).

> - In outer space you have a ship with hallways lined with brains that can speak.

That ship is the Lexx, the brains are the Divine Predecessors.

> - There's screens where you have people on conveyors they start getting closer to the saws on the wall were they get what looks like gutted and then bagged.

Happens in the first film.

> - At the end, I'm not sure if it was a ship or something but it was a giant brain and it was showing screens where this guy's head was in it and still alive talking to the brain.

The thing (more a giant insect than a ship) was the Gigashadow and that brain was its brain.

Comment: More specifically, this all happens in the low-budget made-for-tv movie-length pilot-episode.

Comment: @Richard - not exactly all of it; some of what the question asks is from the 4th tv-movie they made, I know the last bit with the brain-eating worm is at least.