# Looking for a Sci-fi movie that’s on VHS

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I was young when I watched it so sorry for the vague details. The movie was in color and I have a guess it was released in the 90s due to the visual effects but that is just a guess. To my memory there are red/orange dragonfly like ships kind of like personal helicopters. I believe there was around some alien species infecting humans as the lead actor at some point goes to a stadium and releases some monster worms (kind of like tremors) to destroy the place.

Comment: You're describing the 1984 version of Dune

Comment: Or the first Lexx :)

Comment: It is lexx Thank you so much for helping! @moopet

Comment: @Moopet - Worth posting an answer, although I'm 98% certain (without checking) that this'll turn out to be a dupe

Comment: @JacobC. - I'm mobile at the moment and couldn't be bothered to check :-) but yes, if there's already a decent story ID with Lexx as the answer it should get duped to that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Science fiction movie with a hallway lined with brains and a conveyor with saws](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102742/science-fiction-movie-with-a-hallway-lined-with-brains-and-a-conveyor-with-saws)

Comment: Voting to reopen so it can be closed as a dupe.